# How to differ strings with and without ending/starting spaces?

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, whitespace

I need to format a text file (a Fortran source code) and change some keywords from small letters to capitals or vice versa.
I've made an array of possible keywords and have the following piece of the script:

```
 for ((i=0; i<$nwords; i++ )); do
    word=${words[$i]}
    small=${word,,}
    cap=${word^^}
    sed -i "s/$small/$cap/gI" $filein
  done
```

It works as it should. The problem is the following:

Suppose one of the keywords is "use", and somewhere in the test I have a word "uselog".
The script changes it to "USErlog" and I want to avoid it anyhow.
My idea is to put spaces in the keywords, but somehow they are automatically trimmed.
I mean, I try "use " or 'use ' instead of 'use', but the result is the same.

I guess there must be a simple way to do that, like using quotes, parenthesis or similar, but so far I have not found one.
Other alternatives are welcome as well.

Comment: Does the source code contain literal strings where the keywords could also appear (e.g. `print*,"You cannot use that function for this data"`) but where they should _not_ be transformed?

Answer (score 0):

with `GNU sed` you can use word boundry `\b`

> Matches a word boundary; that is it matches if the character to the left is a “word” character and the character to the right is a “non-word” character, or vice-versa.

```
sed 's/\bword\b/newword/g' file.txt
```

Simply just for putting `space` in the keyword:

```
sed 's/\sword\s/ newword /g' file.txt
```

please note that the **neword** have one space at each side.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've jujst tried it. It helps, but only partially. I mean, I have about a hundred of keywords, and for some of them this method works, but for some it does not work

Comment: @MikhailModestov ok what are the conditions for those other keywords?

Comment: It's hard to say. I've just noticed that other keywords work without \b option, and they do not work with \b option. Although it is weird, because in that particular case there was also a space after that keyword.

Comment: So still, ideal, to my mind, would be to have a possibility to check exact matching with a word including possible spaces around it.

Comment: @MikhailModestov I updated the answer.

Comment: OK, the second option with adding \s in the sed command works! Thank you.